# Recommend a good .NET 4.0/SQL Server 2008 web host (shared platform)

Tags: sql-server, hosting, web-hosting, .net-4.0

I posted this on StackOverflow which was obviously not the right place so I'm cross posting this here too, hopefully that's OK! Sorry!

---

Hi all,

This is my first question so play nice!!! I've done a search and could only find similar questions relating to .NET 3.5 last year so I thought I'd ask for people's recommendations at this point in time regarding a good web host to use for a small e-commerce website that will run on .NET 4.0 with a SQL Server 2008 back end.

Opinions on hosts seem to change daily as do their offers and the technology that they support so I'd love to hear what people are using at this time and how they're getting on. I generally run everything through GoDaddy but their Shared hosting packages only support SQL Server 2005 at the moment, I called them and to get access to a SQL Server 2008 database you have to go down the Virtual Server route which will cost too much for this project.

I'm looking at around the £5/month marker, unlimited bandwidth would be nice but not essential given that the site receives about 400 visitors per month.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I went with [WinHost](http://www.winhost.com/windows-hosting-plans.aspx) in the end and am now up and running. Setup at least was faultless.

Comment: How many concurrent users is WinHost able to handle?

Answer (score 0):

For £5/month you are going to be very limited in hosts that might have .NET 4 with SQL 2008, and you are very likely to be limited in what they will allow you to do.  If you were willing to spend more to get more, I'd recommend MaximumASP which has done a number of partnerships with Microsoft in the past to provide hosted environments for testing out SQL Server 2008 features.

http://www.maximumasp.com/products/sharedHosting/features.aspx